# Basic Topology: Interior of a Given Topology

Tags: general-topology

The open half-line topology = {($a$,+$\infty$):$a \in R$} $\cup$ {$R,\varnothing$}.

What would the interior of a set in this topology look like?

My text states that, Let A = [1,5). Thus in the open half-line topology, $Int(A) = \varnothing$.  I do not understand why.

I am trying to understand so that I can apply this to other sets A, such as Z, R - Z, Q, and R - Q.

Comment: Does $A$ contain any open set?

Comment: A contains (1,5) but that is not open in this topology since it is not of the correct form (a,$\infty$).  Is that why Int(A) is $\varnothing$?

Comment: Indeed, $A$ does not contain any open set for this topology. The interior of $A$ being the union of all open sets contained in $A$, this implies that the interior is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is the basis for the topology. Consider the set $A \ = \ [1, \ 5)$, as the text says. We can see that there exists no union of intersection of "half intervals" $(a, \ \infty)$ contained within this set, as the an open set of this form necessarily extends off to positive infinity. Thus, the only open set contained in $A$ is $\emptyset$.

This same logic applies to any real interval in our topological space that does not extend to infinity.